# API POST request - Python example to Google Script - 'Unexpected end of JSON input'

Tags: python, google-apps-script, post, urlfetch

I'm trying to connect a Google spreadsheet to snov.io service using an API POST request, they have provided a Python code as example and I have tried to run the google script below based on it, but without success. Any ideas? Thank you :)

Python (provided by the company)

```
def get_access_token():
params = {
    'grant_type':'client_credentials',
    'client_id':'c57a0459f6t141659ea75cccb393c111',
    'client_secret': '77cbf92b71553e85ce3bfd505214f40b'
}

res = requests.post('https://api.snov.io/v1/oauth/access_token', data=params)
resText = res.text.encode('ascii','ignore')

return json.loads(resText)['access_token']
```

Google Script (Error:SyntaxError:'Unexpected end of JSON input')

```
var params = {
    'grant_type':'client_credentials',
    'client_id':'c57a0459f6t141659ea75cccb393c111',
    'client_secret': '77cbf92b71553e85ce3bfd505214f40b',
    'method':'post'
}
var url = 'https://api.snov.io/v1/oauth/access_token';

var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url,params)
var json = response.getContentText();
    obj = JSON.parse(json);
    token = obj.result.access_token;
    return token
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to achieve the same request with your python script, how about modifying your Google Apps Script as follows?

#### Modified script:

##### From:

```
var params = {
    'grant_type':'client_credentials',
    'client_id':'c57a0459f6t141659ea75cccb393c111',
    'client_secret': '77cbf92b71553e85ce3bfd505214f40b',
    'method':'post'
}
var url = 'https://api.snov.io/v1/oauth/access_token';

var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url,params)
```

##### To:

```
var params = {
  'grant_type': 'client_credentials',
  'client_id': 'c57a0459f6t141659ea75cccb393c111',
  'client_secret': '77cbf92b71553e85ce3bfd505214f40b',
}
var url = 'https://api.snov.io/v1/oauth/access_token';
var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, {method: "post", payload: params});
```

- In this case, even when `method: "post"` is removed, the same request is achieved.

#### Reference:

- [fetch(url, params)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#fetchurl,-params)

Comment: Hello Tanaike, thanks for the fast reply. The UrlFetchApp worked! But it is not showing any results after that, when I try to get their token, it is showing the error : "Cannot read property 'access_token' of undefined". I may have to contact Snov to check my credentials.

Comment: @SKuan Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. About `Cannot read property 'access_token' of undefined`, for example, did you confirm the returned value by `console.log(response.getContentText())`? If the access token is not included, I agree with `contact Snov`.

Comment: thanks for the explanation. The console.log(response.getContentText()) returned some data and I was able to figure it out what was happening! So I had to remove the 'result' from (token = obj.result.access_token) . Question marked as solved, thanks for the help!

Comment: @SKuan Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.